# how to get a branch created by coworker?

Tags: svn

we have several branches under the "branches" folder. now coworker created another new branch, dev4, under the "branches" folder. I don't want to do update at the "branches" level because there are few branches I don't need them. I don't want to do checkout because the .svn may be created there. how can I do this with SVN command line command?

Comment: Perhaps 'svn switch htttp://your-svn.repository.url/branches/your-coworkers-branch' is what you are looking for?  That will modify your local checkout of (whatever branch you are currently on) so that it becomes a local checkout of your co-worker's branch instead.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more why you do not want to do a checkout of only this branch ? Note that you can use `svn export` if you do not want .svn folders.

Comment: *"I don't want to do checkout because the .svn may be created there. how can I do this with SVN command line command?"* you should seriously consider reading the documentation first.